# Linear Logic Question About Exponentials

Tags: logic, linear-logic

In Linear Logic (L.L.), exponentials {!,?} are used to allow the rules of Weakening and Contraction for formulas under their scope. It is a theorem of Linear Logic that
!(P⊗Q)⊸!(P&Q) where ‘⊗’ is multiplicative conjunction, ‘&’ is additive conjunction, and ‘⊸’ is linear implication. So, since Linear Logic is resource sensitive, is it the case that for any L.L. formulas Φ and Ψ, !(Φ⊗Ψ)⊸!(Φ&Ψ) ?

Comment: Er, how did you come to the conclusion that $!(P \otimes Q) \multimap\ !(P \& Q)$ is a theorem of linear logic?

Comment: As far as I know, $ ! (P \otimes Q) ⊸ \ !(P \,\&\, Q) $ is not provable in linear logic. Moreover, I don't understand the question. What is the difference between $!(P \otimes Q)⊸ \ !(P \,\&\, Q)$ (which you claim to be provable) and $!(Φ \,\otimes\, Ψ)⊸ \ !(Φ \,\&\, Ψ) $ (for which you're asking if it is provable)?

Comment: figured that it was invalid myself, but I plugged it into a proof checker which validates it. This is the site: https://click-and-collect.linear-logic.org/?s=P%5E%E2%8A%B8%28%21%28P*Q%29%29%5E&autoReverse=1

Answer (score 1):

If the formula $!(P \otimes Q) \multimap\ !(P \& Q)$ was a theorem of Linear Logic, then by the identity expansion property  $!(\Phi \otimes \Psi) \multimap\ !(\Phi \& \Psi)$ would be a theorem as well for all formulas $\Phi, \Psi$.

The issue is that, contrary to what you wrote, the formula $!(P \otimes Q) \multimap\ !(P \& Q)$ is **not** a theorem of Linear Logic. You can confirm this by showing that $!(P \& Q) \multimap P$ holds in Linear Logic, while $!(P \otimes Q) \multimap P$ does not.

Intuitively, think about buying shoes: if $P$ is the option to buy the left half of a pair of boots for £100, and $Q$ is the option to buy the right half of a pair of boots for £100, then the policy $!(P \otimes Q)$ just states that you can buy as many pairs of boots as you'd like for £200 each. But the policy $!(P \& Q)$ is much more permissive: it allows you to buy just the left half of a pair of boots for £100, without paying for the corresponding right half at all.

Comment: I figured that it was invalid myself, but I plugged it into a proof checker which validates it. This is the site: https://click-and-collect.linear-logic.org/?s=P%5E%E2%8A%B8%28%21%28P*Q%29%29%5E&autoReverse=1

Comment: Well, as far as I can see, click-and-collect **does not** validate $!(P \otimes Q) \multimap\ !(P \& Q)$. If it did, that would be a serious bug since this is not a theorem of LL - but I very much doubt that it does. You should try to edit the post with a screenshot of the proof you think you managed to produce using click-and-collect.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the tree that click-and-collect produced as a proof since I’m unfamiliar with L.L.